# How do I delete a range of indexeddb keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

I want to delete a range of keys that begin with `tracklist/RANDOM_STRING` and `'songBook/RANDOM_String'`.

I tried achieving it with  IDBKeyRange but I can't really wrap my head around how they work.
I used this documentation, but I find it somewhat confusing: [Mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange)

```
await db.delete('store', IDBKeyRange.lowerBound('trackList/'))
await db.delete('store', IDBKeyRange.lowerBound('songBook/'))
```

[image: IndexedDB -> Store]

Comment: So you mean it deletes unwanted data?

Comment: Kind of, I want to delete the tracklists (they are downloaded songs) from the store. Therefore I use the .delete function. And as the second parameter, you can add a IDBKeyRange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IDBKeyRange.lowerBound("trackList/")` will delete all keys that are greater than or equal to `trackList/`, regardless of whether they start with `trackList/` or not. The `songbook/RANDOM_STR` key is greater than the `trackList/` key because it comes after it in the lexicographical order.

So you can use `IDBKeyRange.bound()` method for deleting a range of keys.

For example:

```
await db.delete('store', IDBKeyRange.bound('trackList/', 'trackList/\uffff'));
await db.delete('store', IDBKeyRange.bound('songBook/', 'songBook/\uffff'))
```

In this code, `\uffff` is the highest Unicode value, so you can delete all keys that start with `tracklist/`.